# Specifier resolution: %i and %I difference?

Tags: systemd

I'm trying to run celery as a service as described [in the docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/v4.1.0/userguide/daemonizing.html#usage-systemd).

The documentation uses `%n%I` specifiers for the log files:

celery.service:

```
ExecStart= [...] --logfile=${CELERYD_LOG_FILE}
```

celery.service.d/celery.conf

```
Environment="CELERYD_LOG_FILE=/var/log/celery/%n%I.log"
```

When doing this, I can see in the service status that `%n` is resolved at start time and %I remains at this stage:

```
systemctl status celery.service
[...]
    --logfile=/var/log/celery/worker%I.log
```

And I get those log files:

```
/var/log/celery/worker.log
/var/log/celery/worker-1.log
/var/log/celery/worker-2.log
```

If I use `%i`, however, the whole thing resolves at start time

celery.service.d/celery.conf

```
Environment="CELERYD_LOG_FILE=/var/log/celery/%n%i.log"
```

produces this:

```
systemctl status celery.service
[...]
    --logfile=/var/log/celery/celery.service.log
```

And I get only one log file:

```
/var/log/celery/celery.service.log
```

This is troubling.

From [systemd documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Specifiers), the only difference should be about escaping:

- "%i" | Instance name    | For instantiated units: this is the string between the "@" character and the suffix of the unit name.
- "%I" | Unescaped instance name  | Same as "%i", but with escaping undone

Is there something I'm missing, here?

Also, I noticed that if I set the log path directly in the `.service` file, only the `%n%i` form is accepted.

```
ExecStart= [...] --logfile=/var/log/celery/%n%i.log
```

will do, and results in

```
/var/log/celery/celery.service.log
```

while

```
ExecStart= [...] --logfile=/var/log/celery/%n%I.log
```

triggers an error:

```
celery.service failed to run 'start' task: Operation not supported
Failed to start Celery worker.
```

How come?

I'm using [systemd 215-17](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/systemd) on Debian Jessie.

Edit 1:

It seems `%I` is not understood by `systemd` at all. What we see when using `%I` is specific to Celery. (See [Celery docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html?highlight=workers%20guide#node-name-replacements)). So `%i` is managed by `systemd` while `%I` is ignored and passed transparently by `systemd`, then managed by Celery.

This explains a lot but leaves a few questions open:

- Why doesn't `systemd` understand `%I` here?
- Conversely, what if I wanted to pass Celery a `%i`?
- Why does it differ if I pass the option directly in the `.service` file rather than in the `.conf` file?

I went through `systemd` changelog and didn't find anything about `%I` being more recent than the version I am using.

Edit 2:

I saw this error message while running `systemctl status celery.service`:

```
[/etc/systemd/system/celery.service.d/celery.conf:18] Failed to resolve specifiers, ignoring: "CELERYD_LOG_FILE=/var/log/celery/%n%I.log"
```

I can't reproduce it, though. I can't tell why it happened once and and not every time.

Comment: The celery doc you refer to is not using a service template, or the unit file would be named `celery@.service` (which you can try).  You should probably replace every % with %% so systemd does no processing of the specifiers, since your celery application seems to be wanting to do it.

Answer (score 18):

From the [documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Specifiers) you already cited, the difference between `%i` and `%I` is the "escaping" of the passed parameter.

The next question is: What does "escaping" mean?

Escaping means changing the special characters. `%i` replaces the special characters `/` by dash `-` and  by `\x20`.

WARNING: if the instance name contains a dash `-`, this dash gets replaced in the variable `%I`. That's why the documentation says "with escaping undone".

### Example

Let's take `some-service@.service` containing the following lines:

```
[Service]
Environment="OPTIONS=%I %i"
ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash -c "echo $OPTIONS >> /tmp/test-specifier"
```

Let's then start the service with: `systemctl start some-service@/etc/path/to/some-conf`
The output in `/tmp/test-specifier` will be:

```
/etc/path/to/some/conf -etc-path-to-some-conf
```

Notice that `some-conf` has become `some/conf` in the  variable `%I`.

#### Conclusion

Thus, the behavior for the instance name `/etc/path/to/some-conf` is:

- `%i` specifier with escaping: `-etc-path-to-some-conf`
- `%I` specifier without escaping: `/etc/path/to/some/conf`

### Test setup

CentOS 7 with `systemd-219-67`

String escaping for systemd can be tried using `systemd-escape` from the command line.

### References

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Specifiers
http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/instances.html
https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-escape.html

Comment: Very informative summary of the docs with a hands on example.